# Nuget - No items found

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I am trying to add following dlls using Nuget but I am getting items not found.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/15/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview/

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.AzureStorage
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.SqlStorage
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.Mvc

**NuGet Package Manager   2.8.60318.667**

[image]

Comment: Now you should get it without ```pre``` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NuGet package manager console from the tools menu and use this command, because this is a pre-release version you cannot get it from the NuGet gui window

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom -Pre
```

Comment: In which directory do I need to run that command? I tried but I got, 'Install-Package' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: From tools> Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager console, open it then type this command and hit enter thats it

Comment: @TechJerk - You can also choose that option in the drop down that says "Stable Only".

Answer (score 1):

The nugets are now 'official' so don't need the '-pre' tag on nugget anymore. You can find them directly [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=microsoft.aspnet.webhooks).

Hope this helps,

Henrik